# Button on ViewPager returning NullPointer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                       at com.fet.minebeta.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)

---

I've this `ViewPager` to display multiple views, there's a single `Fragment`, but multiple layouts, though, each layout's view has the same id (i.e. TextViews have same id, Buttons have same id, etc).

---

I've used a `FrameLayout` to cover all the views in the layout with a gray overlay and a button.

Fact is, when I click that `button` (same id in every layout) it runs an `onClick` method, which should make disappear both the `View` overlay and the button cicked, but I get a `NullPointer` for both when I try to, take a look:

### onClick

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.unlockButton: // If mine purchased successfully, remove overlay and button
            overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mineUnlockButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("### Mine Purchased ###");
            break;
    }
}
```

---

### MineFragment (*not* main)

```
public class MineFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Store instance variables
    private String mName;
    private String mMineral;
    private int mUnlockCost;
    private int mDropRate;
    private int mLayout;
    private boolean mIsUnlocked;

private Button mineUnlockButton;
private View overlay;

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static MineFragment newInstance(String name, String mineral, int  unlockCost, int dropRate, int layout) {
    MineFragment mineFragment = new MineFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putString("MINE_NAME", name);
    args.putString("MINE_MINERAL", mineral);
    args.putInt("MINE_COST", unlockCost);
    args.putInt("MINE_RATE", dropRate);
    args.putInt("MINE_LAYOUT", layout);

    mineFragment.setArguments(args);
    return mineFragment;
}

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments + IsUnlocked
public static MineFragment newInstance(String name, String mineral, int unlockCost, int dropRate, int layout, boolean isUnlocked) {
    MineFragment mineFragment = new MineFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putString("MINE_NAME", name);
    args.putString("MINE_MINERAL", mineral);
    args.putInt("MINE_COST", unlockCost);
    args.putInt("MINE_RATE", dropRate);
    args.putInt("MINE_LAYOUT", layout);
    args.putBoolean("MINE_IS_UNLOCKED", isUnlocked);

    mineFragment.setArguments(args);
    return mineFragment;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mName = getArguments().getString("MINE_NAME");
    mMineral = getArguments().getString("MINE_MINERAL");
    mUnlockCost = getArguments().getInt("MINE_COST");
    mDropRate = getArguments().getInt("MINE_RATE");
    mLayout = getArguments().getInt("MINE_LAYOUT");
    mIsUnlocked = getArguments().getBoolean("MINE_IS_UNLOCKED", false);
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(mLayout, container, false);

    TextView mineName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mineName);
    TextView mineCost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mineCost);
    TextView mineMineral = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mineMineral);
    TextView mineDropRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mineDropRate);
    mineUnlockButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.unlockButton);
    overlay = view.findViewById(R.id.grayOverlay);

    mineName.setText(mName);
    mineCost.setText(String.valueOf(mUnlockCost));
    mineMineral.setText(mMineral);
    mineDropRate.setText(String.valueOf(mDropRate));
    mineUnlockButton.setText(String.valueOf(mUnlockCost));

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.unlockButton: // If mine purchased successfully, remove overlay and button
            overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mineUnlockButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("### Mine Purchased ###");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

---

I have put the `onClick` method on both the MineFragment and MainActivity, this is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
ViewPager viewPager;

private Button mineUnlockButton;
View overlay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MineAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    // Initializing
    mineUnlockButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unlockButton);
    overlay = findViewById(R.id.grayOverlay);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.unlockButton: // If mine purchased successfully, remove overlay and button
            mineUnlockButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("### Mine Purchased ###");
            break;
    }
}


}
```

---

**EDIT**:
Whole Project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/SnipCode/MineBeta)!

Comment: you forget to set the onClick button listener in activity, do this mineUnlockButton.setOnClickListener(this)  :)

Comment: I've set that in the XML Layout, using the onClick attribute @dex

Comment: In fact, the method works, but it tells me the button and the View are Null, added the Error log up above the question

Comment: on then you don't need onclick listener any more just use like this public void unlock(View view){ // do your work }, remove onclick from activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Activity "MainActivity.java" Do this

```
public void Unlock(View view) // since you are setting onclick from XML
{
   // Do your stuff
}
```

and remove View.OnClickListener from activity, it is not required.

Comment: I can't add a method inside onCreate, I tried to put it outside of it but still get the error

Comment: @FET could you share that file with me ? (if possible) [ after changes ]

Comment: Here's the project on GitHub, just uploaded: https://github.com/SnipCode/MineBeta

Comment: @FET actually your xml  doesn't have button view, you need to set button click listener in fragment where xml have button.

Comment: Why can't I put an onClick method in the fragment and then link it to the button using the XML?

Comment: you can put in your fragment but not in activity as your activity has no access to your button view but since fragment is inflating that xml which has button view so you can put on click listener there.

Comment: But why an onClick listener? Couldn't I just implement the onClickListener and then Override the onClick() method?

Comment: you could do that but your activity have no idea which button id you are talking about as button id is not binding to your activity as because it is not inflated by activity but is inflated by fragment

Comment: So I have to set an OnClick listener on the button on the MineFragment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122445/discussion-between-dex-and-fet).